# Multirow cells in TeX tables

Tags: latex, tex

I'm trying to make a table that is very similar to the [first table](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/book/fulltext/table1.pdf) of Cremona's book on Elliptic Curves, however occasionally I want to have cells that span multiple row. I am not opposed to using LaTeX packages, but I have not been able to figure out how to use variable width columns which respect vertical bars around centered columns.

(This code from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) makes the centered columns appear to be right aligned

```
    \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | c | c | c | r | }
    \hline
    label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
    \hline
    item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular*}
```

)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least for me it would be beneficial to understand the exact question before answering. Maybe you specify a simple case, where the occasional multi-row cells, the variable width cells, the centering and the vertical bars meet or should meet your requirements. What latex environments/packages did you try?

Comment: For reference, there is a TeX-specific Stack Exchange site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/. You might already find your question there, and it is probably frequented by more LaTeX experts than StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't have LaTeX available here, so I can't try things to fix your problem . However, I'm wondering if you really need vertical lines. You will notice that most professionally typeset books don't use these, since your eyes guide you just fine. For more info about this, I suggest a look at the booktabs package documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the tabular environment instead of tabular*, and your example above will have all centered cols.

I give the following example in order to show both centered multicols and centered multirows (using package multirow):

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | r | }
\hline
label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name of the SLA parameter $\pi$}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Name of the SLA parameter $\pi$}} \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{item 1} & item 2 & item 3 & item 4\\
  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
\hline
item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

All columns and rows meant to be centered are centered.